# How to post HTML message in Facebook wall using facebook c# sdk?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I can post plain text to wall using facebook c# sdk. But when i try to post HTML message, it post message as it is. Is there a way to post HTML message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot post HTML to facebook's wall/feed.  However, if you want to include a link, picture, or video, you can include those as attachments by specifying the appropriate fields.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: is it possible to add link and picture or video in the same post?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not an "attachment".  they are fields on the post object.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: Some games on the facebook like citywille can send post with picture, link and text. It seems that it is possible. Do you know how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think that it is possible, because in source code of Facebook messaging, there is a property named `html_body` and its default value is `null` so I think that it can be changed by some method and then HTML messaging of wall posting may be possible.

Comment: Nope, I tried and facebook just doesn't send the message

Comment: The `html_body` tag is what the server sends to the client.  So in other words that has been rendered from server side script.  I believe you could if you had permissions available to you, but other than that the answer appears to be no.